# How to monitor VPN traffic with Wireshark on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, wireshark

I'm running Wireshark 1.6.7 (latest available release) x64 on Windows 7 x64.
I only have a single network card on this computer, and Wireshark shows only it as an available adapter to capture packets on.

If I establish a VPN connection (using Windows' built-in VPN client), Wireshark:

- doesn't show any additional adapter to capture packets on, and
- doesn't see *any* network traffic flowing through the VPN tunnel.

How can I monitor the traffic on a VPN connection using Wireshark on Windows 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible at all :-(

http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm#Q-5

Answer (score 3):

Not useful for all scenarios, but one workaround is to run Virtualisation. Run your VPN on your host, and then run the traffic and wireshark capture on the Guest machine

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to capture PPP/VPN traffic with Wireshark on Win7 OS. 
[How can I configure Wireshark to list my dial up connection as a possible capture interface?](https://serverfault.com/questions/75939/how-can-i-configure-wireshark-to-list-my-dial-up-connection-as-a-possible-captur)

Maybe you can try this tool;
http://www.splunk.com/product

Comment: Useful, but -1 for spamming. That product looks in no way like a network sniffer.